# Visual Basic: Is there a way of retrieving the last recieved Skype message as string?

Tags: vba, message, skype, skype4com

I am trying to make an application in Visual Basic where a feature which involes retrieving the last recieved message in Skype as a string comes in quite handy. I have tried messing around a little bit with the Skype4COM API, but I cannot find a way to do exactly that.

So is there a way of getting the last recieved skype message as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you have your skype object setup, lets say it's called skype,
you would get last message as string like this:
    lastmessage = skype.Messages.Item(1).Body;